# Want to sum the contents of one row based on the matching contents of another (don't know if SUMIF applies)

Tags: excel

This is the desired result of the operation

[image: This is the desired result of the operation]

So the function should sum all the B values for all matching A values.

Comment: I would suggest either a pivot table (easiest) or if you are dead stuck on the format to use VBA to loop through each row.

Comment: Yea, I know this is probably easy with VBA, but I'm not very good at using it yet. Will try to investigate the "pivot table" sulution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entered into C1 and then expanded to C1:C4 :

```
=IF(A1<>A2,SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B),"")
```

The IF checks to see if the next row is different, then if so, it uses SUMIF.  If your data isn't sorted, you can do a slightly more complicated check to see if there are no more values of A1 below it (using COUNTIF).

Comment: And yes, a pivot table would also be pretty simple for this.

Comment: When you enter "A1" as a criteria in SUMIF  what does that do? If the criteria "defines which cells will be added" this doesn't make much sense to me? is this some kind of a convention in excel (like, if you enter A1 it sums "up to A1"? Because when I varied it leaving everything the same it seems to behave that way ...

Comment: SUMIF(A:A,A1) tells Excel to compare each value in A:A with A1.  Any cells that return TRUE will then be summed (or, if the third argument is present, their corresponding value in the to-be-summed column is added) to the total.